# Can Nokogiri render Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am curious if Nokogiri can see JavaScript. If not, what is the best way to get around it without anything like Watir or PanthomJS?

For example, the photos on this page are controlled by JavaScript: http://twotreesny.com/residential/rentals/110livingston

They are not shown when I disabled Javascript. In this case, what is the best way to grab these images?

Comment: "rendering" is entirely different than "seeing", "interpreting" or "parsing". Nokogiri can see JavaScript embedded in a page, just like you can when you view the source, it just doesn't parse or interpret it.

Comment: Please don't create multiple instances of the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri is actually just a parser for HTML. You need a browser engine, like Selenium, or WebKit, which will load the page like your browser does, and run the JavaScript scripts.

The easiest way for you would be to build some crawler with Capybara + Phantomjs.